# How should I save MailMessages to file?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, xaml

I am not sure how I should save `MailMessages` to file so they can be read from and displated in the WebBrowser control at a later time.

Which format should I save as?

I am using the AE.NET Mail IMAP library, and this is the code that I have come up with. Just not sure how we should save the message body's.

```
int count = client.GetMessageCount("Inbox");

if (count > 0)
{
    AE.Net.Mail.MailMessage[] messages = client.GetMessages(0, 10, false, false);
    foreach (AE.Net.Mail.MailMessage message in messages)
    {
        collection.Add(new Message()
        {
            Id = message.MessageID,
            Sender = message.From.User,
            Subject = message.Subject,
            Content = message.Body
        });
    }

    list.ItemsSource = collection;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save the mail as xml and with a little xsl-transformation you can display the mail easily. For example:

mail.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="email.xsl" ?>
<email>
    <id>1</id>
    <sender>Ali B</sender>
    <subject>Oops</subject>
    <content>What ever...</content>
</email>
```

email.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="id">
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="sender">
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="subject">
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="content">
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```